# Share Google Form's result publicly with a link

Tags: google-forms

I would like that the user who completed the form can share the answers to his questions with a link, and anyone with that link can see the answers. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a built-in feature of Google Forms. It's possible that there are Google Forms Add-ons that does this.

By using Google Apps Script we could get the edit response URL but there isn't a "view response URL".

One alternative is to copy the responses out of Google Forms, like using Google Documents, then sharing the corresponding document.

A *hacky* alternative is to add a required "edit authorization code" (secret code) question having an answer validation **after** that all responses were got. Then send the corresponding edit response URL to each respondent. In order to edit the responses they should know the "secret code"

NOTE: Google used to block forms having questions for passwords, so don't use Password instead of "secret code"

Related

- [How can I set a Google Forms survey to read-only?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90639/88163)
- [Is there a way to generate edit response URL for Google Form?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86396/88163)

Comment: @RandomCoder99 I edited my answer.